# Scrapy installation confusion

Tags: python, installation, scrapy, virtual-environment

I´m new to scrapy and do face some problems to get it running.
My System is a Win10 machine with a dedicated folder for python.
I use Atom for my python code.
I used Anaconda Navigator to install scrapy and the package exists in the folder anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

I created a venv with

`python3 -m venv jobsearch`

and activated that environment.
Within Atom I changed to that venv with success:

[image]

Package for that is atom-python-virtualenv 1.0.4 and within the settings of that package I adjusted the according path to C:\Users\usr\python_testing\ as $Home and Additional virtualenv to the according project-folder.

Now I tried to

```
import scrapy
```

but Atom says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\usr\python_testing\jobsearch\jobsearch.py", line 1, in 
> import scrapy
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
> [Finished in 0.154s]

Is there anything I missed during installation/setup?
I tried to uninstall and re-install scrapy already and I tried it via pip install as well but that didn´t help. The scrapy-documentation isn´t helpful as their troubleshooting paragraph is only focussing on one issue.

Can anybody guide me to the right direction?
If you need more info on my system or other features just let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/)

Install Scrapy:
`conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`

Comment: That didn´t work as it throws a syntax error on the '$'-character: Invalid Syntax. Can you explain, what should happen with this "under the hood"?

Comment: Don't copy the commands with $. $ shows you are in the terminal.

Comment: That looks different on my machine (I have the foldername in front of the path to indicate virtual environment is running). But now it throws different errors like this: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\usr\python_testing\jobsearch\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jh7sno8j\\twisted_a84220b9f3ac47a698f6c315f08df959\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jh7sno8j\\twisted_a84220b9f3ac47a698f6c315f08df959\\setup.py...

Comment: Follow the installation guide for Windows: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned

Comment: the log lines `C:\Users\usr\python_testing\jobsearch\Scripts\python.exe.....` after installing anaconda - clearly indicates that you are trying to use default pip based python env (not anaconda based)